Is it possible to create publication and replication slot in the same transaction?
I try to create PostgreSQL replication slot by the next command:
DO $$
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_publication WHERE pubname = 'trade_events_pub') 
THEN

    CREATE PUBLICATION trade_events_pub FOR TABLE 
        public.trade_events;

END IF;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from pg_catalog.pg_replication_slots WHERE slot_name = 'trade_events_slot') 
THEN

    PERFORM pg_create_logical_replication_slot('trade_events_slot', 'pgoutput');

END IF;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

I get the error:
[25001] ERROR: cannot create logical replication slot in transaction that has performed writes Where: SQL statement "SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('trade_events_slot', 'pgoutput')" PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 15 at PERFORM
If I try to run command CREATE PUBLICATION and PERFORM pg_create_logical_replication_slot in separate transactions it works fine.
I use PostgreSQL 15.3

The error message answer your question, doesn't it?

I'm not sure. I know some people ran the same commands and it worked. I'm trying to understand what's wrong in my case.

The SQL statements inside a DO statement run in an enveloping transaction, that's why you get the error. The people who can make it happen don't do that (or they create the replication slot as the first statement).

I'm curious what is write operations here. When I hear 'writes operation' my first thought is something like insert or update operation. But what it means in this particular context? What or who does these writes perform? CREATE PUBLICATION?

For example. Anything that modifies the state of the database.
